# Rails rename model name in url dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I have a model named item. Each item belongs_to category (another model), which has an attribute called name.

When seeking any item, I see the url as /item/:id

instead, I would like the url to show up as /'item.category.name'/:id

e.g. if the item belongs to category whose name is "footwear", then, I would like to see the url as /footwear/:id. And if there is another item that belongs to category whose name is "clothing", then I would like to see the URL as /clothing/:id

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup a route like

```
# config/routes.rb
RouteTest::Application.routes.draw do
  get ':category_name(/:id)', to: 'items#show', constraints: {id: /\d+/}
end
```

It will map to the show action in your ItemsController, and in there, you will have access to params[:category_name] and params[:id]. With this information, you should be able to get the data you want and render it.

Note that this route however will likely have the undesirable effect of masking any routes that follow. You could use rails advanced route constraints to further narrow down 'which values would be considered valid category_names' but this wouldn't be a very scalable or manageable approach.

For example, you could do something like

```
RouteTest::Application.routes.draw do
  get ':brand_name(/:id)', to: 'items#show', constraints: lambda { |request| BrandList.include?(request.params[:brand_name]) }

  # etc. ...

  get ':category_name(/:id)', to: 'items#show'
end
```

but this only really works well when the BrandList is a finite list that you could setup during application initialization.

A better, more scalable approach might be to design your URLs like

```
/brand/adidas
/brand/teva
/shoes/1
/shoes/2
/jackets/45
```

IOW, prefix known namespaces like `brand` with an appropriate human friendly URL prefix and use category based route as a catch-all at the bottom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One question - what if I have another route added to this - get ':brand_name/:id', to :items#show If brand_name and category_name have a common value (e.g. 'nike'), which parameter will get passed to items#show, params[:brand_name] or params[:category_name]?

Comment: Looks like it will match the one for which the route is defined first.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment - looks like it will always default to the first route defined

Comment: Updated to address the question about this always matching and masking other routes that follow.